# How do I query document where datetime == datetime in Firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem try to query a document using DateTime object

document in path /users/{userId}/payments/{paymentDoc}
which I have document structure like this

```
Document data: { 
  banking: '',
  isPaid: false,
  endDate: Timestamp { _seconds: 1592179200, _nanoseconds: 0 },
  startDate: Timestamp { _seconds: 1590969600, _nanoseconds: 0 }, **June 1, 2020 at 7:00:00 AM UTC+7**
  totalIncome: 100 
}
```

where I try to query document is

```
firstDayOfMonth = new Date(2020, 05, 01) **maybe wrong here?**
userPaymentRef = db.collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .collection('payments')
  .where('startDate', '==', firstDayOfMonth)
  .get()
  .then(function (doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");
      return false;
    }
 }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("Error getting document:", error);
 });
```

But in firebase functions log its said **No such document!**

I try to log the timestamp of startDate I stored and timestamp of date I want to query. It's the same, but it's said 'No such document' is my query is wrong? or DateTime I want to query is wrong?

**Edit:**
Functions log

the timestamp of document I store and the timestamp from DateTime is matched but can't find document

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timestamp field field in a document, it can only be matched exactly by other Date or Timestamp objects.  The precision down to the nanosecond must match.  Two timestamps with the same day but different times of the day are not equal.

Also bear in mind that the timestamp objects don't encode a timezone - they always use UTC.  If you use a Date object, it must be created with the exact same moment in time as the timestamp in order to get an equality match.  Date objects that don't specify precise moment in time will use the local computer's timestamp, which is definitely not guaranteed to match the time of day on any other computer.

The bottom line is this: if you want two timestamps to be equal, *they must both represent the exact same moment in time, measured to the nanosecond*.

Comment: now I'm using admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(firstDayOfMonth)                                
timestam from payments doc:  { _seconds: 1590969600, _nanoseconds: 0 }
timestamp from firstDayOfMonth :  { _seconds: 1590969600, _nanoseconds: 0 }

I think it's precisely the same
still No Such **No such document!**

Comment: Are you sure the userId also matches?  We can't see that the query exactly matches your data.

Comment: I'm sure that userId is matched because I only one test user haha. btw I add the query result in the question

Comment: I don't understand that output - it doesn't seem to match the code you show here.  Please edit the question to show the source data, the specific query, and the query results.